# How do I omit a column separator in a tabular environment?

Tags: tables

I'd like to create a layout like this (it's for a resume):

```
some text here                                            a little more 
big chunk of text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah |
...blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah |
...blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah |
...blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bla. |
```

So I figured a `tabular` would get me most of the way there. Here's what I'm using:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|p{3cm}}
    some text here & a little more \\
    \parbox{big chunk of text blah...} % because there's actually a list environment inside
\end{tabular}
```

but of course that produces this:

```
some text here                                            | a little more 
big chunk of text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah |
...blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah |
...blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah |
...blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bla. |
```

- Is there a way to omit the vertical line (the column separator) in the first row?
- Or, is there an entirely better way to pull this off? Simplicity is a plus.

The two goals are a fixed-width right column, and a vertical line in the empty lower-right cell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can omit the vertical separator in the first row by using `\multicolumn{1}` followed by another; e.g.,

`\multicolumn{1}{l}{some text here}&\multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{a little more}`

That will omit the vertical line separator, but will not align "a little more" with the vertical separator.

Comment: Excellent. Any suggestions for aligning "a little more" with the vertical separator?

Comment: @Matt Ball: Other than adding some negative space "by hand", no, sorry.

Comment: No worries, I figured it would be something like `\hspace{-5mm}`. Thank you!